# Conditional Stylesheet Rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

This is just a quick question for clarification really, I have a style sheet for ie7 and need to call it when someone is browsing via IE7, would the following in my application/layouts file call the ie7 stylesheet?

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "ie7", :media => "all" %>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should only bring in that stylesheet for IE7 and older browsers.

I find it's generally better to add a conditional class to the html tag via the following snippet, and then precede your IE rules with `.lt-ieX`.  This allows you to keep all your related rules together in the same stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

e.g.

```
.alert {
  color: red;
}
.lt-ie7 .alert {
  color: blue;
}
```